# Recommended accounts with ReactJS Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a beginner in programming and I try to learn ReactJS/NodeJS/Typescript by doing projects. I'm trying to do some kind of social media and I came across a problem. On the sidebar I would like to show different users from my database ( MySQL ). At the moment I don't want them to be based on the number of followers or popularity, but I would like it to be random.

This is my `sidebar.tsx` :

```
import React from 'react'
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';
import './Sidebar.css';
import { RiMenuUnfoldFill } from "react-icons/ri";

const Sidebar: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    
    <div style={{ width: 250 }}>
      <div className="s-titletoggle">
        <h4>MENU</h4>
        
      <button id="sidebarToggle">
          <RiMenuUnfoldFill /></button>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <ul className="sidebarRows">
        {SidebarData.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            
            <li key={key}
              className="row"
              id=
                {val.path === window.location.pathname ? "active" : ""
                }
              onClick={() => (window.location.pathname = val.path)}>
              
              <div id="s-iconcontainer">
              {val.icon}
              </div>
              <div id="s-titlecontainer">
              <h3>{val.title}</h3>
             </div>
            
            </li>
            
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Sidebar;
```

and this is my `SidebarData.tsx` :

```
import React from 'react'
import { ImHome } from "react-icons/im";
import { MdExplore } from "react-icons/md";
import { RiLiveFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { HiUserGroup } from "react-icons/hi";
import { GiLaurelCrown } from "react-icons/gi";
export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    path: '/',
    icon: <ImHome />
  },
  {
    title: "Live",
    path: '/live',
    icon: <RiLiveFill />
  },
  {
    title: "Rooms",
    path: '/chat',
    icon: <HiUserGroup />
  },
  {
    title: "Statistics",
    path: '/stats',
    icon: <GiLaurelCrown />
  },
  
]
export const SidebarUsers = [
  {
    title: "Alexander",
    path: '/users/alexander',
    icon: 
  },
]
```

I would need their profile picture and their name. I didn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're new to programming the hardest thing is to know what you're actually after (as hinted by Michael).

My guess is you want some random mock data.

So hitting google with "mock data users and profile pictures" or similar would hopefully point you in the right direction.

Example: Perhaps you could use https://randomuser.me. Their documentation shows you could make an API request in your app to their free mock API like this: https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,picture&results=20 to get random user data including profile picture. An easy start to would be to just to hit it and copy paste of the resulting json. That way you will get the same data all the time though.

To actually make the request you can do a simple fetch request:

```
async function getMockedUsers() {
  const mockDataUrl = "https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=name,picture&results=20";
  try {
    const response = await fetch(mockDataUrl);
    const users = await response.json();
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    throw `Mock data fetch failed. Error: ${error}`;
  }
}
const users = await getMockedUsers();
console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry!  I didn't know exactly how to explain because I'm still learning. But I would like users to be from the database (mysql)

Comment: No worries! I see. If you already have an endpoint which can serve json data then you'd more or less just switch the mockDataUrl above. Otherwise you'll need build the backend API endpoint (which is a huge topic)